# WireMock. Ignore all request beside only one

Tags: wiremock

I start WireMock as standalone process:

java -jar wiremock-standalone-2.6.0.jar --port 8080 -v

OK.

When http request content suffix */api/profile/Favorite/*  the WireMock must return stub response. On all other requests must by ignore by WireMock and must be forward to production server.

How I must config WireMock for this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for proxy behavior. For standalone WireMock you pass in `--proxy-all="http://yourserver.com"` as a parameter.

The section on [Record and Playback](http://wiremock.org/docs/record-playback/) in the docs has more examples.

Comment: OK. It's work. Another solution: java -jar wiremock-standalone-2.6.0.jar --port 8080 --enable-browser-proxying